# Select file to upload from source

Tags: php

On a webpage the user can select a file to upload then if he submits the form he is directed to the next webpage with a similar, but bigger form. The form elements are filled with the data he entered on the last page

firstpage.html

```
<form name="MyForm" action="nextpage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="name" size="50">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="40">
</form>
```

nextpage.php (partial form, two elements are the same)

```
<form name="MyForm" action="thirdpage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="name" size="50"  value="<?php echo $name?>">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="40">
</form>
```

Is it possible to preselect a file in the file upload element? If he types his name in the name element on firstpage.html, the same element is filled with the name on nextpage.php. But if he selects a file on firstpage.html, is it possible that he doesn't need to select it again on nextpage.php?

Comment: Save the uploaded file from step 1 on the server, use a hidden field to pass some kind of identifier for the saved file into step 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, security reasons.

If file was already uploaded, there should be info about it, possibility to delete it and upload something new.

Comment: In the first step I just let the user select it. In the next page he fills out the rest of the input fields and uploads the file.

Comment: So remove it from first step if it not uploaded, include it with `rest of input fields`

Comment: From the first page I can retrieve the file name, but not the path for sec. reasons. So at first I should upload the file to the server and then how could I automatically fill out the file input field with this file?

Comment: Please look again at my answer, especially `It's not possible` part.

Comment: I don't see why it is a security risk to select a file from the server automatically in the file input field, but ok.

Comment: `type="file"` is used to select file from client side, not server side. And if you have file name that means file was uploaded in first step. In that case see second part of my answer.